# when constructor throws an error, auto_ptr does not destruct object

Tags: c++, constructor, exception, auto-ptr

I know **auto_ptr** destruct object automatically when it is out of scope. But when Constructor throws exception, it does not destruct object(take a look at below code snippet).

Let me explain below code , I have class A which has an auto_ptr field "autoPtr" (which has a pointer to Test class). In below scenario, A class constructor throws "Malloc" error. I am expecting Auto_Ptr to call Test  class destructor but it does  not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        cout << "Test Constructor" << endl;
    }
    ~Test()
    {
        cout << "Test Destructor" << endl;
    }
};

class A
{
private:
    int *ptr;
    auto_ptr<Test> autoPtr;
public:
    A():autoPtr(new Test()), ptr(NULL)
    {
        ptr = (int *)malloc(INT_MAX);
        if(ptr == NULL)
            throw exception("Malloc failed");
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        A *obj = new A();
    }
    catch (exception e)
    {
        cout << "Caught exception :" <<e.what()<< endl;
    }
}
```

Output is :

Test Constructor

Caught exception :Malloc failed

---

Why **Test class destructor was not called** in the above code ?

Also **Who frees A class object** (**obj**) memory ?

Comment: Please update your question with a complete compileable example of the problem. This code does not compile.

Comment: Which compiler you use? http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wuD6nXGVyY33R39l works as expected.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Same result with vc: http://rextester.com/ZPZO52891
Are you sure, that your code is compiled and not old version is used?

Comment: For your second question: The compiler will free the allocated memory if the constructor throws. Then the `obj` is never assigned a value.

Comment: @ForEveR, usually I compile c++ code in "Visual Studio Developed Command prompt" (it does not need visual studio project, it just need single cpp file) there I received wrong output. Now I have created c++ project, now I am getting correct output as expected. My main problem got solved. Do you know who frees A class object memory ? (in the above code)

Comment: @Siva The destructor of `A` isn't called, because allocated the instance dynamically `A *obj = new A();` and you never call `delete obj;`

Comment: Why are you using `auto_ptr` and not `unique_ptr` ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I understood why destructor is not called. But some one has to free allocated memory ? right ?.  A *obj= new A() is two step process 1) memory allocation for object 2) object initialization through constructor.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I am not familiar with unique_ptr. I will learn about it. Thanks for advice

Comment: @siva _"But some one has to free allocated memory ?"_ It's you who's in charge to do so.